# Thread dump showing thread not releasing lock.

Tags: java, scala, mesos, thread-dump, jstack

- As shown below in the thread dump, thread with id            `qtp336276309-556300` obtained `org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger's`
  lock & did not release it.
  This causes other threads to be BLOCKED.
- This is sometimes accompanied by CPU utilization on the host machine consistently increase over a week from 5% to 30%.
- Would like to know whether the threads in **Blocked state** could cause CPU spike? If yes, then how can I approach to fix the problem?
- If no, then what else should be reviewed in case of resolving spiking CPU utilization?
- Thread dump is as below:

  ```
  "qtp336276309-561036" #561036 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efe80576800 nid=0x20a7 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007efe19fbd000]
     java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
      - waiting to lock <0x00000000e02333c0> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
      at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:601)
      at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:224)
      at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:301)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:788)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.info(Logger.java:1490)
      at org.apache.mesos.chronos.scheduler.api.TaskManagementResource.updateStatus(TaskManagementResource.scala:43)

  "qtp336276309-561035" #561035 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efe80193000 nid=0x20a6 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007efe248f4000]
     java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
      - waiting to lock <0x00000000e02333c0> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
      at mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog.write(ChaosRequestLog.scala:15)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog.log(NCSARequestLog.java:591)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

     Locked ownable synchronizers:
      - None

  "Thread-328668" #561032 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efe50052000 nid=0x62 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007efe6b0cb000]
     java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
      - waiting to lock <0x00000000e02333c0> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
      at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:601)
      at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:224)
      at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:301)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:788)
      at java.util.logging.Logger.info(Logger.java:1490)
      at org.apache.mesos.chronos.scheduler.mesos.MesosJobFramework.statusUpdate(MesosJobFramework.scala:224)
      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:37)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.statusUpdate(Unknown Source)

     Locked ownable synchronizers:
      - None


  "qtp336276309-556300" #556300 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efe81654800 nid=0x2047 runnable [0x00007efe1a1c0000]
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
      at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
      at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
      - locked <0x00000000e0234470> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
      at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
      - locked <0x00000000e0234450> (a java.io.PrintStream)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
      - locked <0x00000000e0234438> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
      at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
      at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
      at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
      at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
      at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
      - locked <0x00000000e0233cc0> (a org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender)
      at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
      - locked <0x00000000e02333c0> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
      at mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog.write(ChaosRequestLog.scala:15)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog.log(NCSARequestLog.java:591)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

     Locked ownable synchronizers:
      - None
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> As shown below in the thread dump, thread with id  qtp336276309-556300 obtained org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger's lock & did not release it.
>   This causes other threads to be BLOCKED.

This is normal, only one thread can be logging to a file at any one time. If you have multiple threads trying to write at once, they have to wait.

> This is sometimes accompanied by CPU utilization on the host machine consistently increase over a week from 5% to 30%.

While logging is a very common cause of slowness, it usually doesn't get worse over time.

What often causes a problem is logging too much, and you might be logging more over time which could result in an increase, however I would see if something else is causing more activity. i.e. logging might just be the symptom.

> Would like to know whether the threads in Blocked state could cause CPU spike?

BLOCKED threads don't use much CPU. While this can result in higher latencies, you might not see any increase in CPU usage (in fact it might go down)

> If no, then what else should be reviewed in case of resolving spiking CPU utilization?

I would look at what other threads are doing at this time. I would try reducing the logging to reduce the amount of "noise" so you can see what it is doing most of the time.

Comment: Thanks @Peter.
- As a takeaway, I agree that a deployment with reduced logging level may be tried.
- Another observation I didn't share above is regarding OS patching. After the patching CPU utilization seems to be consistently maintained at ~5%. Two weeks since the patching the issue of cpu utilization spiking does not seem to be repeating. Care to comment?

Comment: The issue was caused due to a cron job running in the background to collect docker logs!
using root logger fixed it.